# Why does pushing this object into my array give me a number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So, I was building a simple rest api on node, I fixed the problem, but I was just curious as to why I even get a number 4 to begin with? You'll know what I mean when you look at the code, It's just a small snippet of code that I'm confused about.

`main.js`

```
const people = [
  { id: 1, firstName: "Daniel"},
  { id: 2, firstName: "Erika" },
  { id: 3, firstName: "Christian"},
];

let person = people.push({ id: people.length + 1, firstName: "Mark"})
```

If I console.log(person) I get 4 as a value. I mean I understand that If I console.log(people) I will get what I added, but I'm just curious as to why when I console.log(person) I get a value of 4?

Comment: [`Array#push()` returns the new length of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: `Array#Push` => Returns - *The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.*

Comment: Array.push returns the new length of your `people` array :)

Comment: [Why does Array.prototype.push return the new length instead of something more useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34259126) | [javascript push returning number instead of object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43769201) | [Array.push return pushed value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23354896)

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, as @VLAZ said, `Array.push` returns the new length of your `people` array.

If you want to get the last `person` inserted in `people` array you could do:

```js
const people = [
  { id: 1, firstName: "Daniel"},
  { id: 2, firstName: "Erika" },
  { id: 3, firstName: "Christian"},
];

let person = people[people.push({ id: people.length + 1, firstName: "Mark"}) - 1];
console.log(person)
```

`-1` because the 4th element of the array is the object in position 3

Comment: Or you could just create a variable `person` do `people.push(person)` and you don't need to get the same object back from the array, as you already have it.

Comment: @VLAZ easier and better!